# Are results of observable quantum phenomena (experiments) always statistical amounts of waves/particles (which aren't)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, quantum-interpretations

This question probably will or should be substantially revised...or even deleted and completely overhauled.

The question is about quantum indeterminism, experimental capacities and limits of quantum mechanics/QM-interpretations and similar to "[Could quantum randomness be transformed into classical, macroscale randomness?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/505873/could-quantum-randomness-be-transformed-into-classical-macroscale-randomness)". It may relate to the [Ensemble interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_interpretation) or similar interpretations (or criticisms of more popular interpretations from that angle)...or at least about something which would either affirm or invalidate (some of) these.

In the double-slit experiment the screen usually or always (?) records so many photons that the result is not that of one photon but a large amount of photons, basically an aggregate "statistical" result. Are there variants of the experiment in which "individual" photons (or photon-systems including entangled & split pairs) are recorded separately or different experiments in which the result is basically not aggregative pattern but one quantum event's indeterminate (semi-random) result?

I think radioactive decay during a specific time-interval could also be considered to be an aggregative result for e.g. intervals larger than a quantum of time if such exists (or why not?). Was there ever something like a double-slit experiment in which a macro-result (like one dot appearing on a discernible location of an otherwise blank image) was caused by an "individual" photon rather than an amalgamation of quantum events? For instance, is there a quantum randomness generator in which an (e.g. double-slit) experimental setup was tested for which two locations have the same overall chance of a photon landing on each and then outputting which of the two locations(/regions?) was reached by a photon (or at least reached first)?

Comment: Are you just asking if we can send one photon at a time through the double slit setup?

Comment: No, but it's not far from what I'm asking about. It's about the type of measurement _results_ we can get.